Renovate or Rebuild?
Long story short - we got our dream lot at a very affordable price in an otherwise unaffordable area (it is the most desired in our city due to the large lots and wooded areas) - but the house is unlivable.
We have two options (we consulted many professionals):
-Renovate about half of the home for $350k and then live in a half finished home for a year or more before starting to finish the rest (total renovations needed are quoted at $700k).
-Continue to pay both mortgages for awhile (current residence and new house/lot) - which we can do comfortably due to the very reasonable price - and then tear it down and build a new home for about $450k.
Obviously a new build is a scary thought but so is the thought of dumping that much money into this house for renovations and still have many restrictions (the ceilings are too low, the layout is restrictive, there’s a lot of unused land so we don’t have the amount of space we’d like).
Has anyone ever faced something like this before? Any advice?
Note: This is a live in for 20+ years home for us, if not forever.

If 700K does not get you what you want, but 450k does, what is the problem?  Do not know if anything in the old house is worth keeping, but if there is stuff like good old doors, fancy moulding, it can be removed before just bulldozing the house down.

Don't know where the 450 came from, but it's not uncommon for construction costs to spiral up when homeowners realize that the initial price specced builder grade faucets, hollow doors, basic appliances etc. Just know what you're getting at the outset and either stick to the plan or budget for upgrades.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really related to DIY.

VTC because not DIY. But DIY might be a solution. If you have the time and energy and desire to put in a lot of work yourself (i.e., DIY) then you may find you can cut down a huge part of that $700k. In most places you can be your own general contractor/handyman/etc., hire cheap help (in my area they hang out around Home Depot and similar stores) for the heavy-duty stuff, and only need licensed professionals for electrical (varies - in some places you can by default or with an easy "homeowner's test/license" do your own electrical), water and gas. So this could be turned into:

It costs way too much ($350k x 2) to renovate professionally, and I don't want to wait for a new build ($450k and a year) to move in, how can I do...myself repeated x n questions until you have the details you need to get it done at much lower cost. But many people don't have the time, energy, physical ability or desire to do that much themselves. Your choice.

This is simple math except for some unanswered questions here.  Why spend 700K on reno when you can tear down and build new for 450K and get exactly what you want? ( New is going to hold valve longer as well)
UNLESS!
The mortgage on the newly purchased property has a call clause that would make the note due if you tear down the old house.   Perhaps talk to the lender and reveal your intentions and ask for an amendment to the mortgage to rebuild.  They may even  convert the loan to a construction/ perm for you and save you some costs.

Well, the answer is, it depends what the new mortgage costs.
